# How does pandas treat timezone when reading from a CSV file?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timezone

In my CSV file I have the following entries:

```
Local time,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume
01.01.2015 00:00:00.000 GMT+0100,1.20976,1.20976,1.20976,1.20976,0
01.01.2015 00:01:00.000 GMT+0100,1.20976,1.20976,1.20976,1.20976,0
01.01.2015 00:02:00.000 GMT+0100,1.20976,1.20976,1.20976,1.20976,0
01.01.2015 00:03:00.000 GMT+0100,1.20976,1.20976,1.20976,1.20976,0
```

The first column contains date-time in a specific timezone (`GMT+01`).

I read the CSV file using the following command:

```
df = pd.read_csv(csv, sep = ',', parse_dates = ['Local time'])
```

As a result I get the following:

```
0   2015-01-01 01:00:00 1.20976 1.20976 1.20976 1.20976 0.0
1   2015-01-01 01:01:00 1.20976 1.20976 1.20976 1.20976 0.0
2   2015-01-01 01:02:00 1.20976 1.20976 1.20976 1.20976 0.0
3   2015-01-01 01:03:00 1.20976 1.20976 1.20976 1.20976 0.0
4   2015-01-01 01:04:00 1.20976 1.20976 1.20976 1.20976 0.0
```

As we can see timestamp has been modified (one hour has been added to it). My interpretation is that the time has been converted to `UTC` timezone. However, I am not sure about it because, according to Google:

> GMT+01 is a time offset that adds 1 hour to Greenwich Mean Time (GMT).

So, time in `GMT+01` should be 1 hour larger than in `UTC`. So, in `UTC` it should be one hour earlier. So, `00:00`, should become `23:00` and not `01:00`.

Where do I make an error in interpretation?

**ADDED**

I have played a bit with pandas `to_datetime` function. It looks like it is the reason of the above described behaviour.

If I apply it to the time given in the same format as in my CSV:

```
pd.to_datetime('01.01.2015 00:00:00.000 GMT+0100')
```

then I get the same result:

```
Timestamp('2015-01-01 01:00:00')
```

So, as you can see, 1 hour is added (as before).

However, if I apply it to a bit modified format (which I thought is the same):

```
pd.to_datetime('01.01.2015 00:00:00.000+01:00')
```

Then I get another result:

```
Timestamp('2014-12-31 23:00:00')
```

To summarise, `GMT+0100` and `+01:00` are treated differently. Why is that? Do I misinterpret something?

**ADDED 2**

So, it looks like it is about how python treat timezones. If I execute this command:

```
pd.to_datetime('01.01.2015 00:00:00.000').tz_localize('Etc/GMT+5').tz_convert('GMT')
```

I get this:

```
Timestamp('2015-01-01 05:00:00+0000', tz='GMT')
```

I would expect that in the `GMT+5` timezone, the time is 5 hours larger than in `GMT`. So, in `GMT+5` it should be later. However, it looks like it is the other way around. But why?

When I play with this site: https://time.is/GMT+5 , I do see that GMT+5 has 5 hours more than GMT.

**ADDED 3**

From the [documentation on the timezones](https://pvlib-python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/timetimezones.html) I got this:

> The 'Etc/GMT*' time zones mentioned above provide fixed offset
>   specifications, but watch out for the counter-intuitive sign
>   convention.

So, it looks like they treat the sing counter-intuitively. It looks like I have found a solution but now I am not sure how 'GMT+0100' should be treated in my CSV (it has nothing to do with Python), it was just downloaded from a website. Is there a standard convention on what `GMT+0100` means?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but the first step in debugging would be to experiment with [dateutil.parser](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html), since the [Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) says that is the default datetime parser. You can see if the error lies there or somewhere else.

Comment: It looks like it considers the time you passed as UTC and then converts that to GMT+01. What a weird behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pandas relies on your computer locale and some heuristics. If the datetimes come out weird, specify the exact format.

```
df = pd.read_csv(csv)
pd.to_datetime(df['Local time'], format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S.%f GMT%z')

0   2015-01-01 00:00:00+01:00
1   2015-01-01 00:01:00+01:00
2   2015-01-01 00:02:00+01:00
3   2015-01-01 00:03:00+01:00
Name: Local time, dtype: datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(60)]
```

Many functions do not work with timezone-aware datetimes, so you may want to convert everything to a single timezone, then drop the timezone altogether:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Local time'], format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S.%f GMT%z') \
    .dt.tz_convert('America/New_York') \
    .dt.tz_localize(None)
```